# How To: Delete a Facebook Test User

Tags: facebook, testing

I was wondering if anyone happened to know how to delete a facebook test user. I've been perusing through this site for quite awhile now and haven't been able to uncover anything related besides a single unanswered post regarding deleting a facebook test user associated with 2+ apps. Facebook now offers a UI within their dev site which allows this functionality; however, I'm trying to perform the same operation through a C# script utilizing the Graph API and issuing the relevant HTTP commands. Tried monitoring the requests made through the UI using netmon/Fiddler but wasn't able to uncover anything useful. Help, any & all will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ - the section marked 'Deleting':

```
https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_USER_ID?
  method=delete
  &access_token=TEST_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN (OR) APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So I've tried issuing the above url straight from my browser, substituting the appropriate values of course, and I'm receiving a 400 Bad request error. (Example: https://graph.facebook.com/100003222943659?method=delete&access_token=AAAAAAVaXWUsBAGiZAmKUn7iSHCNcqVGYqFmPu9O7tXoM0PWr6Uamxkav7kfDlfYydOJP2clBY3H5MIQ5j4ZCJvla7zCZAs1CnxZBymNa6w25TQG4IuBS)

Comment: Is it a test user who was created via the API or the tool on the developer site? Does it work with the app access token instead of a user access token? (don't include your app access token here for security reasons!)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the TEST_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN to work. I did get the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN to work. Here is what worked for me.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<TEST_USER_ID>?method=delete&access_token=<APP_ID>%7C<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FB graph API as follows:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{test-user-id}?method=delete&access_token={user-access-token}

You should get the following response:

{"success":true}